# Tell node under no circumstances ever to install package

Tags: node.js

how can i configure my package.json to tell node under no circumstances, to ever even attempt to install the node-sass or gyp module, primarily because it will be a cold day in hell before i install VS2013 and python2 on all my dev machines.  Its easier to break the apps than update the dev machines.

oh, and i should probably mention the whole thing about node-sass downloading the file from github doesn't work for me.  my 100 architects can get to github, but the other 1800 developers can not.  its blocked on our firewall.

Comment: Can you provide a virtual machine image or a docker image with the dependencies baked into it?

Comment: no.  not for this.

Comment: my security audit team has already decertified python2, which means its not allowed to be on anything in the company (the OS guys love that BTW) and it would take me 2 years to get VS compilers approved.  Took me 5 years to get GIT approved

Comment: now, if there was a way to redirect that download from github to one of my internal servers, i could make that work to download the binary, other than that, this has got to go

Comment: There's a lot of discussion about dealing with [offline work](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/145724408060/dealing-with-problematic-dependencies-in-a), but I can't think of a way to explicitly exclude dependencies other than to simply pay attention to what you put in your package.json.  There might be some kind of scrubbing of package.json you could automate to flag known bad stuff.

Comment: There is a way to redirect the download: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md#binary-configuration-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/scottty881/dependency-ban which would allow you to add a bannedDependencies section to your package.json, e.g.:

`{
  "bannedDependencies" : {
    "node-sass": "a cold day in hell..."
    "node-gyp": "python 2 decertified"
  }
}`